# np.loadtxt ignores the header, how can I save the header data?

Tags: python, numpy

I've saved an numpy array using savetxt and given the array a header. When I read the file using loadtxt, the header is ignored and only the data is saved in my new array. 
How can I access the header as it has important information I want to save as a string.

Edit:

```
np.savetxt(file_name, array, delimiter=",", header='x,y,z, data from monte carlo simulation')
data = np.loadtxt('test', dtype=float, delimiter=',')
```

**I want to get "data from monte carlo simulation" and save it as a string.**

Comment: Please provide the code you use to save and load the data.

Comment: savvetxt writes the header with a comment character.  loadtxt ignores comment lines by default,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the header you can simply read the first line of the file using `.readline()` method on your file. In your case It would look something like this :

```
f = open(filename)
header = f.readline()
last_col_name = header.split(',')[-1] #returns 'data from monte carlo simulation'
```

Also if you want to look into a more versatile way storing data you can check out the pandas library.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you for your help. I think when you do f.readline the second time it reads the next line but using header.split(',') works.